# Capture image and record video from specific camera

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am developing a project with C# which is using the directshow.net library. In this project I am using three web cams and I am able to find all three using the library.

The problem is that I don't know how to capture image or record video from any specific web cam among the three.

Any help or suggestion would be help me.

Comment: Why you have been unable? Please show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check camera moniker display names - they identify the devices. See more details:

- [How to choose a video capture device?](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/476239/Howplustopluschooseplusaplusvideopluscaptureplusde)
- [How to identify a video device correctly?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/b9b19705-6805-4625-97dd-ac357f0ed394)